# Is it possible to retrieve raw files from atlassian stash without? Raw parameter? (e.g. with additional subdomain?)

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I have several repositories with [RAML](http://raml.org/), [Swagger](http://swagger.io/), and [json-schemas](http://json-schema.org) hosted in corporate bitbucket (on-prem deployed, previously called Atlassian Stash). These files have relative references to other files.

I need to load these hosted files from [web application](https://github.com/mulesoft/api-console) from specified bitbucket namespace, repo & branch, without implementing any additional server with hosted checked out files (this requires one more server, synchronisation, maintenance, and further corresponding problems).

Also, I want to perform direct requests to bitbucket (stash), because this will bring all access features support out of the box: you will able to see only files you have access to.

Best way to implement this - implement `raw` subdomain, like it is implemented in GitHub. You specify path (namespace, repo, branch, filepath) and get raw file, e.g. `raw.git.your-company.com/NAMESPACE/repo/branch/path-to-file.ext`

Is it possible (and how?) To implement with Atlassian stash? I know that you can append every file with `?raw` parameter and stash will return it in raw format. But hosted files can contain relative references, that will not contain `?raw` parameter, so it will not work.

Comment: What is wrong with a simple checkout ? git checkout -- path?

Comment: @CodeWizard updated question. Simple checkout is not acceptable - i do not want to implement one more hosting for files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: This is now possible from Bitbucket Server (formerly known as Stash) in [version 4.7](https://extranet.atlassian.com/display/BSERV/Bitbucket+Server+4.7)

Previously: Currently this isn't available I'm afraid, but it is something we're planning to add. You can watch [this feature suggestion](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-4036) for updates

Comment: by your link I see `fixed` but `/rest/api/1.0/projects/WIR/repos/python-learning/raw/Archive.zip?at=refs/heads/feature/files` return 404

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich, it is not a REST url. Try it without the /rest/api/1.0 part